# Selecting rows using grep vs using ==

Tags: r

I am brand new to R

I tried to select rows from a dataset using the following:

```
1. completeResults <- results[ results$Final_Status=="TSICompleted"]
```

It returned the full dataset even though the (seemingly) logical equivalent works:

```
2. timesTrimmed<-times[times$totaltimemins<60,]
```

Then after doing some research, I tried the following which does work:

```
3. completeResults <- results[grep("TSICompleted", results$Final_Status), ]
```

Why does 2 work but 1 doesn't work?

thanks

Comment: the first line should give an error as it is: you're missing a comma

Answer (score 1):

Missing comma

```
completeResults <- results[ results$Final_Status=="TSICompleted",]
```